# Good quant finance jokes

Tags: soft-question

Have a good quant joke? Share it here. The principle "should be of interest to quants" trumps.

I would be particularly keen to learn jokes which involve some nontrivial finance/mathematics. I am looking for jokes which make you laugh and think at the same time.

This is a community wiki question: One quant joke or pun per answer please.

Comment: I have some jokes with a mathy bent, some of which are quantish at http://www.markjoshi.com/Ashland/Jokes.html

Comment: https://i.pinimg.com/736x/2a/f5/f0/2af5f0e2fc3694017d480fdb8313ceea--circus-peanuts-vintage-comics.jpg

Comment: The little girl in the bottom right frame should be missing. Just the banker should be at the circus. It makes more sense.

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MS2aEfbEi7s) is basically a quant's job.

Answer (score 38):

Efficient Market Hypothesis Joke:

> "There is an old joke, widely told among economists, about an economist strolling down the street with a companion when they come upon a 100 dollar bill lying on the ground. As the companion reaches down to pick it up, the economist says ‘Don’t bother — if it were a real 100 dollar bill, someone would have already picked it up’.”

Comment: Which might be viewed as a practical application of the no-arbitrage principle!

Answer (score 29):

When asked "your money or your life", attempts to calculate the implied volatility.

Comment: That's a nice one!

Comment: ROFL :-))) Hilarious!

Comment: illiquid options theory required

Comment: Also assumes quant's life has non-zero value.

Comment: The quant can have negative net worth.

Answer (score 27):

Adapted from a joke about economists:

A quant(financial engineer), a mechanical engineer, and a chemical engineer are shipwrecked on a deserted island. They are starving, and are tired of eating coconuts.  They come upon a can of food on the beach....

The mechanical engineer says, 'let's wdge the can between these 2 palm trees and rig a branch to chop the top of the can off'   The other two quickly point out that this will destroy the can and likely send the contents all over the place, wasting them...

The chemical engineer says, 'let's take the sea water and reverse the polarity of the water extracting the salt to make an acid and then burn one end of the can off'  The other two quickly point out that while this is clever it will likely ruin the contents of the can.

The quant says, 'let's make a simplifying modeling assumption.... let's begin by assuming that we have a can opener'

:-)

Answer (score 21):

Investment bank Dog competition:

A researcher, a risk manager and a trader each bring a dog to a competition.

The first one to display is the researcher's dog. The researcher brought a bottle of milk a bowl and placed it all on the floor. Then he commanded the dog to take the bottle and pour the milk into the bowl until the maximum amount it could hold. And that is exactly what his dog did.

The second one to display is the risk manager's dog. The risk manager's brought a bottle of milk a bowl and placed it all on the floor. Then he commanded the dog to take the bottle and pour the milk into the bowl until two thirds of the maximum it could hold and without spilling any milk during the whole process. And that is exactly what his dog did.

The third one to display is the trader's dog. The trader did not bring anything other than the dog. Then he commanded the dog to do what he taught. The dog stands up and walks in the direction of each one of the bowls and drinks all the milk.

Answer (score 10):

Q. Why do Quants have the best job in the world? 
A. Because they spend their time looking at MODELS all day.

Answer (score 9):

Two Day-Traders went to go eat (after the market closed of course!). One of the traders orders a steak and has a hard time cutting it. He then asks for a sharper knife... when he unfolds his cutlery the knife hits his plate and falls out of the table and lands right by his foot which was slightly sticking out of the table. The other trader looks at him and says "Why didn't you move your foot when the knife was falling?!" to which he responded, "I thought it was going back up!".

Answer (score 5):

Read it somewhere...

What is the difference between a bond and a bond trader?????

The bond matures.

Here's another.

What is the difference between a hedge fund and a mutual fund?

Mutual funds returns more and are safer.....:)

Answer (score 4):

A Banker explains another banker why he is not getting married ...
"She is hot, but not half my fortune hot".

Answer (score 4):

My girlfriend borrowed £100 off of me.

After 3 years when we broke up, she returned £100.

I had no interest in that relationship.

Answer (score 3):

A photographer and a quant have one thing in common, as they both fall in love with their models...

Answer (score 2):

Who is a quant's favourite actor?
A) Heston

Answer (score 2):

...starts thinking about sexual encounters in term of their Sharpe Ratios.

Answer (score 2):

There are 10 kinds of people out there. Those who understand binary maths and those who don't.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Why are quants never ripped off in Bangkok?

They are good at pricing exotics.

---

Why do quants look so happy?

They work on volatility smiles.

---

What is the difference between a used car salesman and a derivatives salesman?

The used car salesman knows when he's lying.

---

What is the difference between a quant and a Formula 1 racer?

Quants run Monte Carlo, while F1 racers run through Monte Carlo.

---

Why is the FX trader unpopoular with the girls?

Because he keeps his dates short.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting Jim Simons,

> Those kinds of times… when everyone is running around like a chicken
>   with its head cut off, that's pretty good for us…

meaning good for Renaissance Technologies!